# python pyodbc error with query that works fine against ms sqlserver

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

In SQL Server Management Studio I can run this query:

```
select a.foo, colX, colY, colZ from tblA a
join tblB b
on (a.foo = b.foo)
```

Running the same query through pyodbc in python script, I get:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][
SQL Server]"b" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a p
arameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that
your database compatibility mode is set to 90. (321) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Can anyone explain why this query works directly against SQL Server but there seems to be a problem with the table alias when using pyodbc?

**This is what I've been able to find out**:

- SQL Server running on Microsoft Windows NT 6.1 (7601)
- SQL Server version is 11.0.5532.0
- pyodbc library: pyodbc-3.0.7.win32-py2.7

1) I do not know how to produce a reproducible example and I'm not a DBA; I can just about get by in SQL. 2) I cannot create tables on this database. However: I can do the full query with 3 joins / 3 aliases works fine using the RODBC r package and the sqlQuery() call against the same db. Therefore the culprit is pyodbc so I will try to find a python dev to try reproduce and post back the findings.

Comment: Nothing *syntactically* wrong with the T-SQL posted. Please edit the question with the python code used to produce the error.

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue. Please [edit] your question to show your code as @BryanEargle suggested, and also mention the versions of the various components involved (Python, pyodbc, SQL Server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE + FIX**

The issue is caused by concatenation errors:

Got python developer help to find and print raw sql before it was executed in python:

```
select a.foo, colX, colY, colZ from tblA a join tblB bon (a.foo = b.foo)
```

...and similar issue at each join, caused by missing whitespace within the sql string:

```
sql = "select a.foo, colX, colY, colZ from tblA a "
sql += "join tblB" #no whitespace at end of string
sql += "on (a.foo = b.foo)" #runs into next segment.
```

Worked in r with RODBC because string in r built like:

```
sql = "
...full query...
"
```

...with no opportunity for concatenation errors.

Comment: For future reference you can do similar multi-line string literals in Python using `'''` or `"""`. Details [here](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).